# Amazon price target app for Android

Tags: android, finance, amazon, shopping

Looking for an Android app that will tell me when select products are available on Amazon for user-defined prices.

I would think there would be dozens of such apps, but I have yet to find a good one.

The most obvious candidate is [Amazon Price Tracker Platinum](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fastinformation.PriceTracker4Amazon), but the reviews are quite bad, and they indicate that it most likely does not meet requirements #2 and #3 below.

***Requirements:***

1. Runs on Android KitKat
2. Does not run all the time
3. Only checks once per day (or, preferably, at a configurable interval)
4. Does not use excessive amounts of battery or storage
5. Easy to add items from the Amazon app (most likely via the Share menu)
6. Works for items sold by Amazon and their third-party sellers
7. Notifies you via the app or notifications, not via email

***Preferences (but not requirements):***

1. Performs the price checking on a host server and simply sends an alert to the app when a price has been lowered to meet the threshold specified by the user
2. Gratis

Comment: Not tried myself, hence a comment: Take a look at [Price Monitor for Amazon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kitos.monitorpriceamazon) and my list of [Shopping](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/shopping_shopping) apps (just being updated within the next few minutes, so you might find additional candidates in the first group on that page).

Comment: Are you happy with Amazon.com or do zou also want to check sites like  Amzon.co.uk and Amazon.de ?

Comment: @Mawg I'm happy with Amazon.com, although no problem if it includes the others.

Comment: Izzy and I might like that :-)   Thanks for clarifying.  Btw, are zou interested only in products sold by Amazon itself, or by others (e.g used books)?

Comment: @Mawg I think you're asking about item #6 in the requirements.  If so, the answer is products sold by all sellers.  Of course, shipping will have to be factored, since it is a common (and annoying) game on Amazon for sellers to charge less, but make up the difference with shipping charges.